# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^k}}\right)=1+\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p\left(p-1\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, prime-numbers

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^k}}\right)=1+\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p\left(p-1\right)}$$

$P$ is primes.

Interesting question ran across while tutoring. Not sure how to solve it, or even what class it's from.

Comment: Clarified it... P is most definitely primes, but I mistyped,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I calculated correctly, it seems that the answer is wrong. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\zeta(k)}
&= n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m^k}
 = 1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m^k}
 = 1-\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \mu(m) \sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{m^k},
\end{align*}

and taking $n\to\infty$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\zeta(k)} \right)
&= 1-\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \mu(m) \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^k}
 = 1-\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m(m-1)} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{1}{p(p-1)} - \sum_{p,q\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{1}{pq(pq-1)} + \cdots.
\end{align*}

Numerical calculations with aid of Mathematica also suggests that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( n-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\zeta(k)} \right) \approx 1.70521, $$

while

$$ 1 + \sum_{p\in\Bbb{P}} \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \approx 1.77316. $$

Comment: This constant is the difference of mertens $2$nd, and $1$st constant, plus one, a faster converging series is, $$1+\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p-1)}=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n}\ln(\zeta(n))$$ Where $\phi(n)$ is eulers totient function, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html